# Vuetify v-icons are off-centred

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify's v-icons, with Material Design. I want the icons to be centred, but I can't work out how to do it. For example:

```
<div style="margin:auto;">
  <v-icon dark x-large color="#90be6d">mdi-check</v-icon>
</div>
```

[image]

The check mark should be centred. Similarly:

```
<div class="resultIconContainer" style="border-radius:50%">
  <v-icon dark x-large color="#90be6d">
    mdi-check
  </v-icon>
</div>
```

[image]

I've tried all the usual CSS stuff, and nothing seems to work. I do have Material icons specified in vuetify.js:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, the icon had `padding-right: 20px;`

If I change this:

```
i[data-v-2cc88beb] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

It fixes it